# Aggregate functions effecting order data

Tags: sql, t-sql

Since i can't use the Order by statement in a view, i'm experiencing following problem;
So i changed my query a bit today. The query selects and categorises data from a production plant, and calculates the delta between following records, it's very important that the data stays in chronological descending order.

my query, which my view was based on used to look like this

```
select x.*, 
case
    when datum <> lead(datum) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) then 'uitschieter'
    when lead(actie_id) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
when lead(actie_id,2) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,2) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,2) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,3) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,3) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,3) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,4) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,4) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,4) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,5) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,5) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,5) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when actie_id = 36 then 'uitschieter'
    When deltasec > 200 then 'Lange stop'
    When deltasec <200 and deltasec >60 then 'korte stop'
    When deltasec < 60 and deltasec > 10 then 'geen stop'
    else 'uitschieter'
    end as [Categorie]
from 
(select T_event.Actie_ID, 
case 
    when actie_omschrijving = 'foto' then 'nieuw PCB'
    when actie_omschrijving = 'is leeg' then 'start/stop model'
end as omschrijving,
cast(event_timestamp as date) as datum, cast(event_timestamp as time) as 
tijd, 
case 
    when left(custom1,4) like '201_%' then 'UFO'
    when t_event.Actie_ID = 48 then left(custom1,4)
    when t_event.Actie_ID = 36 then 'start/stop'
    end as model,
    custom1, 
    cast(T_event.event_timestamp - Lag(T_event.event_timestamp) over (order by 
    T_event.Event_ID) AS time) [Delta],
    cast(T_event.event_timestamp - Lag(T_event.event_timestamp) over 
(order by 
    T_event.Event_ID) AS real) * 86400 as deltasec
    from T_event
    inner join T_Actie ON T_event.Actie_ID = T_Actie.Actie_ID
    WHERE T_EVENT.Actie_ID in (36,34,48) and t_event.custom1 not like 
'einde%'
      and Event_Timestamp >= '2019-07-22') x
```

i changed the following bit of code

```
When deltasec > 200 then 'Lange stop'
When deltasec <200 and deltasec >60 then 'korte stop'
When deltasec < 60 and deltasec > 10 then 'geen stop'
```

to this, in order to be more precise

```
When deltasec > (4* (avg(case when deltasec< 100 then deltasec end) over (PARTITION BY MODEL))) then 'lange stop'           
When deltasec < (4* (avg(case when deltasec< 100 then deltasec end) over (PARTITION BY MODEL))) and deltasec > (1.6 * (avg(case when deltasec< 100 then deltasec end) over (PARTITION BY MODEL))) then 'korte stop'
When deltasec < (1.6 * (avg(case when deltasec< 100 then deltasec end) over (PARTITION BY MODEL))) and deltasec > (0.1 * (avg(case when deltasec < 100 then deltasec end) over (PARTITION BY MODEL))) then 'geen stop'
```

this edit made it so the data isn't showed chronological, but messes up the chronological order i had before.

As i said; it's very important that this data is ordered by the timestamp, because the delta's are calculated based on their position

i use this query to directly load data into power BI, which does not allow me to use an additional order by statement.

Comment: The 'WHEN' clarifications in your post are irrelevant to the question, they just distract the reader. You question is 'how to sort in power BI?' and not aggregate functions. Enough picking on you =P now to help... Power BI allows ORDER BY in the query; SQL views do not. So, you 'SELECT * FROM v_MyView ORDER BY foo'. Or in Power BI you can set the sorting in the grid object showing the data.

Comment: Power BI doesn't allow order by statements, sadly

Comment: It does with Power BI desktop, in the advance Query Editor. Or... like i said before; use the grid properties. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-sort-by-column